# securing images - php base64 vs readfile

Tags: php

Right now I am using base64 to control who has access to images on my website. I store these images outside of the webroot directory so no one has direct access to them. I then determine who has access to these images by what records they have access to in a postgresql database. Basically if they can query record "a" then they can see picture "a".

```
if (file_exists($pic)) {
    $imgbinary = fread(fopen($pic, "r"), filesize($pic));
    $picbase64 = "data:image/gif;base64," . base64_encode($imgbinary);
    echo('<img src="' . $picbase64 . '" />');
```

How can I use readfile instead of base64 while still maintaining my security? For example when using the readfile method to deliver the images to the clients browser this requires me to use the `$_GET` method to send a variable to a php script that has the readfile and header type that then displays the images on the clients browser. The problem is anyone can look at the html source and see the `<img src=phpscript.php?imagename=foo.jpg />` and then call the script in their browser with any argument they like `http://www.hostname/phpscript.php?imagename=bar.jpg` . With the base64 method I am currently using this is not possible since I do not need to have a separate script to process my images that takes a `$_GET` argument, instead the images are embedded directly in the html page.

Thanks for any help!

-Edit-
Sorry guys I failed to mention that there is also anonymous access allowed and certain information is public. Meaning if you are not authenticated and you can read record "a" you can also see image "a".

Comment: Wouldn't the separate image requests come in with the user's cookie? You could check if a user was logged in and had access in `phpscript.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substantive difference between what you're doing now and what you need to do is to send the files over multiple requests. This requires authenticating or otherwise remembering the user between requests.

What you have right now is:

```
if (file_exists($pic)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

And what you need is:

```
if (file_exists($pic) && user_has_image_permission($pic)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

So the details you need to settle on are the logic behind the `user_has_image_permission()` function.

If you need this to be secure, I'd be inclined to approach this with [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php), but you could also use [cookies](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php).

If you don't mind trading some security for a bit of simplicity, you could use some sort of "url pass phrase", like those commonly used to share documents and files in web services like "anyone with the link" in Google Docs, AWS, private RSS feeds, etc.

Finally, you could use a solution completely outside of PHP, based on http authentication. In Apache, this takes the form of [Access Control](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html).

Comment: -Edit-
Sessions works instead of passing the argument to the php script. Thanks!

Comment: -Edit-
Sessions work instead of passing the argument to the php script. However if you trying to display multiple pictures by changing the session variable and passing it to the image script it will not work. For now I see no way around this but to use base64. Thanks!

Comment: @spaghettiwestern The comments are a bit too small to go into design details, but the strategy is not to save individual files in the session, rather, check the user's session to see what his/her permissions are and then check those permissions against the database to see whether you can display the image that's being requested *right now*.I.e.: User requests image id 50. In the image.php script, check user's permission in session. User's permission is "B". Does B have permission to see image 50? If yes, display the image, if not, send 403 headers.

Comment: @spaghettiwestern For the anonymous case you simply add something to `user_has_image_permission()` along the lines of: "If image is public, return true." Or you could use the following logic: "If file exists AND (user has permission OR image is public)." If you want to chat more in-depth you can contact me via my profile page.

Answer (score 0):

I agree; checking access with a cookie would be the most straightforward way.  If you're looking to speed things up, search for X-Sendfile.  It can offload file transfers to your webserver once they've been authenticated.  It's built in to lighttpd, and there is an apache mod, https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/ .